Can you create custom field for eventrelation object?
I need to 'count' the number of EventRelations for Users.  I'd like to create a custom Number field on EventRelations with a constant value of '1'.  Within Flow, I will map (aggregate) it to the User Target with a custom numeric field (Target).  I do not see how to add a Custom Field to the EventRelations object.  Please advise.

Not all standard objects permit custom fields -- if the option isn't shown in the Object Manager, you can't. If this is on-demand data, you could build a Screen Flow or LWC to shown on demand (would not be reportable)
